# remove duplicates based on one column and combine certain value in one column

Tags: r, duplicates

I am a beginner in R. I have this kind of data,
[data1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiSZK.png)

And I wanted to have a data like this:
[data2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNjR9.png)

I have found examples of people removing duplicates and combine the some data as list. but majority of examples only consist of 2 columns.

Hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using group by operations.  We group by the common columns and `paste` the elements in the column of interest. In the example, it is "X".  Group by summarise can be done using `data.table`, `dplyr`, `aggregate` (from base R) etc.

With `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by multiple columns (here I used `names` to specify multiple columns), and `paste` the "X" column elements.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(X= toString(X)), c(names(df1)[c(1:7,9)])]
```

---

Or using the same method with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr) 
df1 %>%
   group_by_(.dots= names(df1)[c(1:7,9)]) %>%
   summarise(X= toString(X))
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response. But, how if i have much larger dataset that have 3 replicates and want to list all the three in X column (eg. GV,MI, MII)?

Comment: @NAA  The code will paste all those cases.